# Understanding Function Declaration Javascript

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am trying to understand function declaration in Javascript in RXJS Library. I am trying to understand how the function is declared.

https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/scan

```
scan<V, A, S>(accumulator: (acc: V | A | S, value: V, index: number) => A, seed?: S): OperatorFunction<V, V | A>
```

My understanding

1.scan takes three arguments `<V, A, S>`

2.return `OperatorFunction<V, V | A>]`

3.Seed is optional `[ seed?: S ]`

but i am not able to understand what does below mean

`(accumulator: (acc: V | A | S, value: V, index: number) => A, seed?: S)`

Why do we need word

`accumulator:`

and what does below mean, why do we need an arrow function

`=> A, seed?: S`

It should be declared like
`scan<V, A, S>(acc: V | A | S, value: V, index: number)): OperatorFunction<V, V | A>`

Please throw some light.

Comment: That is _TypeScript_, not just JavaScript - see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html. It takes two arguments, one of which is itself _callable_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Understanding the type signature of RxJS' scan operator

```ts
function scan<V, A, S>(
  accumulator: (acc: V | A | S, value: V, index: number) => A, 
  seed?: S
): OperatorFunction<V, V | A>
```

This should be read as follows, scan is a function with 2 parameters.

- The first param is called `accumulator` and is itself a function too. * The second param is an optional parameter called `seed`.

`scan` returns an `OperatorFunction`

Consider this simple function:

```ts
function add(
  a:number, 
  b?: number
): number
```

This should be read as follows, add is a function with 2 parameters. The first param is called `a` and is a number. The second param is an optional parameter called `b` that may be a number.

`add` returns a `number`

---

Let's re-introduce generics and add a function as a parameter:

```ts
function processNumbers<T>(
  process: (x: number, y: number) => T,
  a: number,
  b: number
): T {
  // Implementation
  // Create out value of type T
  const processed: T = process(a*2, b-5);
  // Return a value of type T
  return processed;
}
```

`processNumbers` generic type `T` gets specialized to a concrete type (`string` or `ProcNum` as examples) when invoked:

```ts
// Let's call processNumbers with some arguments
// the processed value will be of type string in this case.
const processed1: string = processNumbers(
  (x,y) => `Result: ${(x / 2) + (y * 2)}`,
  23,
  29
);
// Display our string
console.log(processed1) // Result: 71

// lets call it again with different first argument.
// Instead of a string, we'll process some wrapper type
interface ProcNum{
  num: number
}

// The processed value will be of type ProcNum in this case.
const processed2: ProcNum = processNumbers(
  (x,y) => ({num: (x / 2) + (y * 2)}),
  23,
  29
);
// Display our string
console.log(processed2) // {num: 71}
```

This reads as: `processNumbers` is a function that is generic over any type `T`. It has 3 parameters.

The first parameter is called `process` and it's type is a function that takes two numbers and returns a value of type `T`.

The other two parameters are called `a` and `b` and are simple numbers.

Finally, `processNumbers` returns the same type of value that `process` returns.

When we first invoked `processNumbers` with 3 arguments, the generic type for the function was specialized as a string. Because the arrow function returned a string, that meant the entire function returned a string. You can see why from the implementation.

The second time we invoked `processNumbers`, it was specialized with `ProcNum`.

---

#### A quick aside:

TypeScript didn't do the best job with it's type signatures. When you see something like `variableName: blahblah`, that can be either a TypeScript type signature **OR** it can be Vanilla JavaScript's property initialization.

You should be able to tell from context. Object properties are always part of objects (surrounded by these `{}` like `{a:1, b:2}`) and always initialized by an expression. Everything else is a type signature

Here's both on one line:

```ts
const var: {a:number, b:number} = {a:1, b:2};
```